# How to process a large file from a s3 bucket using spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

Hellow, I am trying execute the example posted in comment of the follow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69652446/how-to-process-a-large-file-from-s3-and-use-it-in-spring-batch).

I`m accessing the bucket and reading a list of file, but when I go execute the reader I receive the follow error message: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): ServletContext resource [/s3://bkt-csv-files/files/23-12-2022/arquivo_jan_2022_pt_00]". How can I resolved this error, or, there is another way to read the files on s3 using spring-batch?

Answer (score 0):

I did not try the example you shared, but I would do it differently.

The `FlatFileItemReader` works with any implementation of the `Resource` interface. So if you manage to get an accessible resource in S3, you can use it with your item reader.

For example, you can use a `URLResource` that points to your file in S3 and set it on the item reader.

This might help as well: [Spring Batch - Read files from Aws S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30832041/spring-batch-read-files-from-aws-s3)